# Convert character to code point in Vim

Tags: vim, unicode

`ga` is useful to get the code point of a character.  However it doesn't put the results into a buffer.  Right now, to convert a character to its code point, I do this:

1. Press `ga` and try to memorize the code point.
2. Press `a` and type whatever I remember because the display has now disappeared.
3. Press `<Esc>4hga` to check again to make sure I got it right.

Unsurprisingly, I make mistakes with this method.  Any suggestions?

After reading [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/555/see-the-unicode-code-point-of-the-current-character), it looks like it would be possible to write a function.  However a solution that doesn't require a lot of customization would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `redir` command will do what you want; it redirects the output of subsequent Vim commands into a file or register. As a proof of concept, I just wrote a short function to do what you want:

```
function GetCodepoint()
    redir @">   " Redirect command output into the unnamed register
    ascii       " Print ASCII value of the character under the cursor
    redir END   " Stop redirection
endfunction
```

Running `call GetCodepoint()` will save the output of the `ga` command into
the unnamed register (`"`) but the `redir` command can be used to redirect the output of subsequent Vim commands into any register you like. See `:help :redir` for all the different ways that it can be called.

Also, the function is short enough that you could probably just run the
commands manually. It would depend on how often you’d be doing this.